# Ubuntu 19.10: Fingerprint login

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader

I installed Eoan and have a acer spin 5 with fingerprint sensor. The sensor is recognized, i enrolled one finger via settings/user. The finger is recognized, but on login, i can swipe the finger for hours, it won't read.

Might be a problem of fprintd/dbus?

Thx!
Ruggerio

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I have the same problem. I'm trying to find some errors from the logs or if the driver is loaded properly to no avail...

Answer (score 1):

So I could solve it by doing 2 things:

- Enable fingerprint authentication
- Re-enroll very carefully

Here are the steps:

1. Enable fingerprint authentication

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

and enabling `Fingerprint authentication`
[image: pam authentication]

Among other things (enabled fingerprint for `sudo` and al), what it did is makes it more verbose messages. It showed me in the login screen that my fingerprint wasn't properly recognized.

2. Re-Enroll fingerprints

So I let my hands under water 20-30 seconds to make the finger skin more soft and better fingerprint quality, then I re-enrolled very carefully and slowly.

Now everything works well (I occasionally need to humidify my finger with a wet towel or dip my finger in my glass of water :D ).